# Using 2 different versions of Jquery at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use the following code to import 2 versions of jQuery, `jquery.1.12.4` works but `jquery.2.1.3` doesn't work.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.2.1.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $213 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.1.12.4.js'></script>
```

the function of `jquery.1.12.4` works but the following function from `jquery.2.1.3` does not work:

```
<script>
    $213(function() {
        var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
            this.el = el || {};
            this.multiple = multiple || false;

            // Variables privadas
            var links = this.el.find('.link');
            // Evento
            links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
        }

        Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
            var $el = e.data.el;
                $this = $(this),
                $next = $this.next();

            $next.slideToggle();
            $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

            if (!e.data.multiple) {
                $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
            };
        }   

        var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need two versions of jQuery?

Comment: `does not work` any errors in the `console`?

Comment: Are you using these 2 versions for some fallback compatibility for older scripts?

Comment: for use from bazaarche.me/all.min.js and above script

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen for use from bazaarche.me/all.min.js and above script

Comment: @cowCrazy i dont think so , that is not correct

Comment: What is the best way
؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the following way it should work if you define `'noConflict()` for both versions

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $jquery_2_1(function(jQuery) {
    var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
      this.el = el || {};
      this.multiple = multiple || false;

      // Variables privadas
      var links = this.el.find('.link');
      // Evento
      links.on('click', {
        el: this.el,
        multiple: this.multiple
      }, this.dropdown)
    }

    Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
      var $el = e.data.el;
      $this = $(this),
        $next = $this.next();

      $next.slideToggle();
      $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

      if (!e.data.multiple) {
        $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
      };
    }

    var accordion = new Accordion(jQuery('#accordion'), false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $jquery_2_1 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $jquery_1_12 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: see above script i modified it , with the available jquery versions, can you add your html code in your OP so that we can test it

Comment: you were not passing `$` or `jQuery` inside your function, have you noticed that change, the error was on the last line `var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);`