# Is it possible to place the entirety of jQuery into a new variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version

I have a website where we load jQuery 3.2.1. In order for one of our widgets to work (provided by a third-party company), it requires jQuery 1.11.0, which is loaded in a separate `<script>` tag by the company's provided code.

Is it possible to load the latter, older version of jQuery, separately, into a new variable, this way I can call it from the widget's JS that needs the older version of jQuery? Is this possible?

Comment: `window.new_var = window.jQuery` ? not sure if that will work

Comment: Using two versions of jQuery on the same page is a recipe for sadness and woe.

Comment: I should've clarified: we load jQuery 3.2.1 in one `<script>` tag, and then the HTML provided by the company that provides our widget loads jQuery 1.11.0 in another `<script>` tag. I was wondering if it was possible to load the latter, older version into its own separate variable somehow.

Comment: @Pointy: Tell me about it. I have no choice in the matter. Unless we downgrade our site's jQuery version, or fight with the 3rd-party vendor to make their stuff work with jQuery 3.x

Comment: why not use jquery migrate ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Use jquery.noConflict function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use from 2 version of jQuery for me doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376991/use-from-2-version-of-jquery-for-me-doesnt-work)

Comment: It probably is, Muhammad, but that question is so poorly worded that it's no wonder I couldn't find it in my SO searches.

Comment: Interestingly enough, we ended up downgrading our jQuery version just to make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

You have to use [`.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to assign a variable other than `$` to the second one loaded.

```js
console.log("1: "+$.fn.jquery);  // Print "1.11.0" in the console

console.log("2: "+jQuery_321.fn.jquery);  // Print "3.2.1" in the console
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery_321 = $.noConflict();  // Assing the variable you wish instead of $
</script>
```

Comment: This did it. I had no idea `$.noConflict()` could be used to load two parallel versions of jQuery together. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure... I think your question will be usefull in the future, since even the jQuery documentation terribly lacks a short example like this. ;)